# Does "as" mean "while" or "because" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> I didn't want to go out **as** I was reading a book.
>
> *I didn't want to go out **while/because** I was reading a book.*

What does "as" mean in this sentence? How can I know if "as" means "while" or "because" here? What about this sentence?

*I can't go out as I am busy.*

Comment: I don't want to go out as I was reading a book. I can't go out as I am busy.  The use of "as" in both sentences may mean while or because.  Whether it means while or because depends on the context.

Answer (score 7):

> I didn't want to go out **while** I was reading a book.

Here *while* indicates concurrent actions.

> I didn't want to go out **because** I was reading a book.

Here *because* indicates cause and effect.

Using *as* could be either one, as you can see in the definitions of [***as***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/as):

> 6) at the same time that; **while**"   ⇒ *she laughed as she spoke*"
>   7) **because**; since"   ⇒ as you object, we won't go"

Context is needed to know what was meant. Or, just don't use *as* in such situations.

Comment: +1 for `Or, just don't us as in such situations.`  I definitely approve of trying to reduce ambiguity!

Comment: Note that a comma would also disambiguate. _I didn't want to go out, as I was reading a book_ would only mean _because_.

Answer (score 5):

Although you could interpret it as "while" and have it make sense, in this case, I would say it means "because".  If you consult [Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/as), you'll find the fifth definition for 'as' used as a conjunction is:

> formal : for the reason that : because
>
> - She stayed home as she had no car.
> - As I'm a pacifist, I'm against all wars.

The reason I wouldn't interpret it as "while" is because I think it sounds odd to use it that way without the progressive form (however, there's no rule that it can't be done).  The following sentence is an example of where I would interpret it as "while":

> As I was going to the store, she was driving to work.

As you can see, 'as' is a very versatile word, so it has a lot of uses (for instance, I've used it multiple times in answering your question!)